# AWS ElasticBeanstalk ebextensions command fails during deployment but works fine when I run it manually

Tags: amazon-web-services, python-2.7, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using  `.ebextensions`  to run some automation commands, but some commands are failing without a explaining the cause issue or printing any informative stacktrace, but when I run the same command manually it works like a charm with no issues:

**the command:**

`` aws logs put-retention-policy --log-group-name `{"Fn::Join":["/", ["/aws/eb", { "Ref":"AWSEBEnvironmentName" }, "var/log/app-log"]]}` --retention-in-days 7 --region `{"Ref":"AWS::Region"}` ``

**the stack trace:**

```
[ERROR] Command 03 (aws logs put-retention-policy --log-group-name /aws/log-group-name --retention-in-days 7 --region us-west-2) failed
2021-04-19 21:33:50,248 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of prebuild_2_squirrel: Command 03 failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 542, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 260, in build
    changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 117, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
ToolError: Command 03 failed
2021-04-19 21:33:50,250 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2021-04-19 21:33:50,250 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command 03 failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 171, in <module>
    worklog.build(metadata, configSets)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 129, in build
    Contractor(metadata).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 530, in build
    self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 542, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 260, in build
    changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 117, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
```

Anyone seen this before or knows what it could be the issue ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

after checking the /var/log/cfn-init-cmd.log, I saw details about the issue, the log group gets created few seconds after, so I just need to wait